# Replace sub array in 2-dimension array

Tags: javascript

i have the below example:

```
const arr = [
  ["1", "2", "3", "4"],
  ["1", "2", "3", "4"],
  ["1", "2", "3", "4"],
  ["1", "2", "3", "4"],
  ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
]
```

`arr` is a 2-D array

```
const subArr = [
  ["a", "b"],
  ["a", "b"]
]
```

`subArr` is a 2-D array too

After replacing the arr with the subArr in position (1,1) , i want the expect result to be:

```
finalArr = [
  ["1", "2", "3", "4"],
  ["1", "a", "b", "4"],
  ["1", "a", "b", "4"],
  ["1", "2", "3", "4"],
  ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
]
```

How can i get it with JavaScript? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An in-place solution can be found below. If you want your `finalArr` to be a new instance then you need to do some (deep) copying of the array before applying the function `embed()`.

```js
 
const arr = [
  ["1", "2", "3", "4"],
  ["1", "2", "3", "4"],
  ["1", "2", "3", "4"],
  ["1", "2", "3", "4"],
  ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
];
const subArr = [
  ["a", "b"],
  ["c", "d"]
];

function embed(subArr,arr,ioff,joff){
// Performs embedding "in place", i. e. in existing array:
subArr.forEach((r,i)=>
  r.forEach((v,j)=> arr[ioff+i][joff+j]=v));
}

embed(subArr,arr,1,1);
console.log(arr);
```

This is still a "bare bones" implementation, as it does not check, whether the subArr does actually "fully fit" into the target array. It might overshoot and will then increase the original dimensions of the target array.

Answer (score 1):

Array function `forEach` can get the job done.

Let's take your (1, 1) as `startY` and `startX`.

```
function replace2DArray(startY, startX, array, subArray) {
  /* Y is every array of subArray, i is it's index */
  subArray.forEach(Y, i => {
    /* X is every item of Y, j is it's index */
    Y.forEach(X, j => {
      let currentY = startY + i;
      let currentX = startX + j;
      array[currentY][currentX] = X;
    })
  })
}
```